# Can you license an original response to a copyrighted work?

Tags: united-states, copyright, licensing, creative-commons

Recently I've had a dispute with a colleague of mine, about a certain legal situation pertaining to licensing.

Let me try to explain:

Person A has a quiz that they created, with only a pen and piece of paper.

Person B responds to said quiz, and only records THEIR answers to said quiz.

Person B decides to license said response under CC-BY-SA 4.0.

Is this legally possible under Massachusetts law? And is this transformative?

Comment: Person B is just publishing “yes, no, 42, London, 1492, false, Elizabeth Taylor and Richard Burton”? They might be good or poor answers to an entirely different quiz?

Comment: @IMSOASIAN See also [this Academia SE question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/179024/149582). It's not the exact same question, but check it out, as it's simaler.

Comment: For copyright purposes, it doesn't matter whether Person A created the quiz with a pen and paper, with a canvas and a paintbrush, with a computer and a keyboard, etc. No matter how you created it, you get a copyright on a creative work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Sure

If the answers are substantial enough to constitute an original literary work - short answers or essays for example.

If they are single word or short phrase answers then they are merely the recitation of (possibly incorrect) facts and do not qualify for copyright - you can't licence something you don't own the copyright to.